# In Android is there an issue holding on to a SharedPreferences object created from the application context for the whole duration of the app?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Thanks for reading. I create a SharedPreferences object from the application context:

```java
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

Is there a problem using this prefs object for the life of the application in a singleton class? or is it better to grab the object as needed?

Comment: What do you mean "hold on"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there's any real harm in holding on to a SharedPreferences instance, but I do think that it is poor style.

In general, you should give variables as small a scope as possible - instantiate them where you need them, and get rid of them (have them go out of scope) as soon as you no longer need them.

SharedPreferences already is a singleton - no need for you to duplicate that.

Answer (score 0):

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext())
```

The above code itself is a singleton way to get shared preference object to that particular application. 
So it is suggested that use a local variable (for a block or a method) and get the access whenever needed through the above call, do the necessary operations and leave it there.